# Using IF to compare 3 values

Tags: ios, xcode, if-statement

I have 3 UILabel Textfields and I am trying to compare a value in each one, to highlight the smallest value.

I currently have the following code:

```
if (((pd1 <= pd3) && (pd1 <= pd2)) || ((pd2 == 0) && (pd3 == 0))){
    pdOne.textColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
}
if (((pd2 > 0) && (pd2 <= pd1)) && ((pd3 >0) && (pd2 <= pd3))) {
    pdTwo.textColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
}
if ((pd3 >0) && (pd3 <=1) && (pd3 <= pd2)) {
    pdThree.textColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
}
```

Somewhere I am going very wrong and would love a little guidance on this.

Many Thanks

the full code for the action is

```
- (IBAction)calculateOne:(id)sender; {

NSLog(@"count=%d",count);

pd3 = pd2;
pdThree.text = pdTwo.text;

pdThree.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:kDefaultFontSize];
//setup text resizing check here
if (pdThree.contentSize.height > pdThree.frame.size.height) {
    int fontIncrement = 1;
    while (pdThree.contentSize.height > pdThree.frame.size.height) {
        pdThree.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:kDefaultFontSize-fontIncrement];
        fontIncrement++;
    }
}

pd2 = pd1;
pdTwo.text = pdOne.text;

pdTwo.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:kDefaultFontSize];
//setup text resizing check here
if (pdTwo.contentSize.height > pdTwo.frame.size.height) {
    int fontIncrement = 1;
    while (pdTwo.contentSize.height > pdTwo.frame.size.height) {
        pdTwo.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:kDefaultFontSize-fontIncrement];
        fontIncrement++;
    }
}



[brand resignFirstResponder];
[qty resignFirstResponder];
[size resignFirstResponder];
[price resignFirstResponder];
double num1, num2, num3, num4, answerb;

num1 = [qty.text intValue];
num2 = [size.text intValue];
num3 = [price.text intValue];
num4 = (num3/100);
count = (count+1);
NSLog(@"count=%d",count);


answerb=((num3/(num1*num2))*10);
pd1 = answerb;

NSString *answerStringc = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@ %@ x %@ml @ £%.2f = £%.4f/litre ", brand.text, qty.text, size.text, num4, answerb];
pdOne.text= answerStringc;
pdOne.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:kDefaultFontSize];
pdOne.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
pdTwo.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
pdThree.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];



if (((pd1 <= pd3) && (pd1 <= pd2)) || ((pd2 == 0) && (pd3 == 0))){
    pdOne.textColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
}
if (((pd2 > 0) && (pd2 <= pd1)) && ((pd3 >0) && (pd2 <= pd3))) {
    pdTwo.textColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
}
if ((pd3 >0) && (pd3 <=pd1) && (pd3 <= pd2)) {
    pdThree.textColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
}

//setup text resizing check here
if (pdOne.contentSize.height > pdOne.frame.size.height) {
    int fontIncrement = 1;
    while (pdOne.contentSize.height > pdOne.frame.size.height) {
        pdOne.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:kDefaultFontSize-fontIncrement];
        fontIncrement++;
    }
}

NSLog(@"pd1 = %f",pd1);
NSLog(@"pd2 = %f",pd2);

if ((count >1) && ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter]) && ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]))  {
    self.tweetButton.enabled = YES;
    self.tweetButton.alpha = 1.0f;
    self.facebookButton.enabled = YES;
    self.facebookButton.alpha = 1.0f;

} else if ((count <2)) {
    self.tweetButton.enabled = NO;
    self.tweetButton.alpha = 0.5f;
    self.facebookButton.enabled = NO;
    self.facebookButton.alpha = 0.5f;
}
```

}

Comment: Could you say, in plain terms, what your intent for each individual if statement is?  Also, if you could tell us what this is doing that is incorrect, and what it should be doing.  That would help us to help you.

Comment: Could you post more code to put this code in context?  Are pd1, pd2, and pd3 `int` variables or something else?

Comment: I have just spotted an error, it is now working better, however the second if statement is now my issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have 3 UILabel Textfields and I am trying to compare a value in each one, to highlight the smallest value.

Simple enough: assuming your values are floats, you can use this:

```
// You want to ignore values that reads 0, so for each value that is zero we will use CGLOAT_MAX instead in the MIN computation.
// Note: "x?:y" is equivalent to "x?x:y"
// and reads "if x is true (not 0/nil/NO), then use x, else use y"
float minval = MIN( (pd1?:CGFLOAT_MAX) , MIN( (pd2?:CGFLOAT_MAX) , (pd3?:CGFLOAT_MAX) ));

pdOne.textColor   = (pd1 == minval) ? [UIColor yellowColor] : [UIColor blackColor];
pdTwo.textColor   = (pd2 == minval) ? [UIColor yellowColor] : [UIColor blackColor];
pdThree.textColor = (pd3 == minval) ? [UIColor yellowColor] : [UIColor blackColor];
```

If your values are integers, use `int minval` and more importantly use `INT_MAX` instead of `CGFLOAT_MAX`.

Comment: the problem is that if a value reads 0. I need it to be ignored. The pd3 and pd2 wont have a value until the 2nd or 3rd calculation

Comment: then add a condition before that if `pd2` is 0, reaffect it to the value `CGFLOAT_MAX`, so that it won't mess with your tests.

Comment: Or use `CGFLOAT_MAX` instead of the values if they are 0, for all three values in the `MIN(MIN(,),)` statement, which is even better. See my edit.

Comment: I must be missing something, as the textcolor is not changing

Comment: I have cracked it, at the beginning of my code I was using `double pd1, pd2, pd3;` instead of `float` Thanks for all your help, I really appreciate it

Comment: cool :) Don't forget to match the type you are using with the "max" constants (`CGFLOAT_MAX` / `DBL_MAX` / `INT_MAX`)

Answer (score 1):

I think this would be more easily achieved and more legible like this (assuming your pd1, pd2, pd3 are ints):

```
// Begin with the assumption that pd1 is the smallest
int smallestValue = pd1;
UILabel *smallestLabel = pdOne;

// If pd2 is smaller, use it
if ((pd2 != 0) && (pd2 < smallestValue)) {
     smallestValue = pd2;
     smallestLabel = pdTwo;
}

// If pd3 is smaller, use it
if ((pd3 != 0) && (pd3 < smallestValue)) {
     smallestValue = pd3;
     smallestLabel = pdThree;
}

// Highlight the smallest
smallestLabel.textColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
```

Comment: This looks good, however, I said the values went to a UILabel, they don't, its a UITextView. I treid replacing UILabel with UITextView but the app crashes at this instance